# Referring to databrowse urls in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'd like to integrate django [Databrowse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/) into my application.

It comes down to pointing to databrowse urls from within template or view for enhanced drill down functionality of the databrowse.

Is there an easy way to extract the url from a databrowse object?

Comment: Databrowse doesn't really integrate very well into anything. It's a bit of an abandoned project, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing mixin class that fetches relevant EasyInstance and reuses the `url()` of it:

```
from django.contrib.databrowse.datastructures import EasyModel
from django.contrib.databrowse import site   

class DatabrowseMixin:
     def url(pyClass):
          if not site.root_url:
               #hack, but root_url is not set until the first databrowse view
               #and resolving urlconf does not work either
               site.root_url = '/databrowse/' 

          easy_model = EasyModel(site, pyClass.__class__)
          obj = easy_model.object_by_pk(pyClass.pk)

          return obj.url()

class MyModel(models.Model, DatabrowseMixin):
     ...
```

Now in my templates I can reuse `my_model_instance.url` tag pointing to databrowse object url.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one easy way would be to just construct the url you want, and pass it into the template:

```
databrowse_url = '/'.join((obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.module_name, 'objects', str(obj.id)))
```

And then in the template (assuming you have databrowse situated at `/databrowse`:

```
<a href="/databrowse/{{ databrowse_url }}">
```

Which would give you a url like: `/databrowse/app_name/model_name/objects/1`.

Comment: Found a way to retrieve url directly from databrowse, but I do like the simplicity of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate the databrowse urls in the format thats show in the [databrowse urls.py](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/databrowse/urls.py)

You might be able to get the [url tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to work in your template by passing the view name + arguments.

However, if you [browse the source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/databrowse?order=name), it looks like databrowse will add a 'url' attribute to the objects it works with.

**EDIT:**

Given an EasyModel instance, you can do the following:

```
my_easy_model_instance.url()
```

Most of the 'Easy' classes have a url() or urls() method on them.

Comment: Any way to pull the url attribute from the corresponding object (`EasyModel`)?

Comment: @Oleksiy: On your EasyModel instance, just call .url(). I'll edit the answer to include that.

Comment: and how would one retrieve the EasyModel object from the class instance? This seems to be the hardest part.

Comment: posted my final version reusing instance, still not exactly what I want, but it is getting closer. Thank you for your help!